# Why boolean difference operation is not working

Tags: modifiers

I have a mesh and want to cut from middle with the cube. I have the boolean modifier and difference operation its not working. I remove double. flip normal. applied scale still not working. Any suggestion or help

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have non-manifold geometry in the cutter. It's 7am here, and I haven't been too bed yet, so I'm too bloody tired to fix it right now, but basically you have parts with zero thickness, i.e. only one face facing both ways, so the boolean gets confused about the normals. [This question and its answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean modifier will need to be applied to the object you want to end up with, in this case the cube. Apply the modifier to the cube with Oval Cutter as the target Object of the modifier. Then hide the Oval Cutter in the Outliner so you can see the result before applying it.

Comment: its not working.. plz download the file and show me how it works